# Android: passing a spinner selection to a new activity

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am working on a project where a user selects up to five options from spinners, I am wanting to display the selected options in a new activity when a submit button is pressed I have a new activity opening on button press but nothing displaying, I am wanting help with the steps I need to do, Here is my code for the second screen where the data is to be displayed

```
    public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {

    TextView FirstIwi;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selected_iwi);





        FirstIwi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

         Intent intename = getIntent();


        String iwi1 = (String) intename.getSerializableExtra("USERNAME"); 
        //Spinner spinnername2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);



        FirstIwi.setText("First Iwi" + iwi1);


    }
}
```

**First class**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

public class IwiSelect extends Activity {

    Spinner spinner1, spinner2, spinner3, spinner4, spinner5;
    Button btnSubmit; 
    String iwi1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_iwiselect);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_iwi_select, menu);
        return true;
    }




    // get the selected drop down list value
      public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);

        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                iwi1 = spinner1.toString();
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(IwiSelect.this, SecondScreenActivity.class);

                //Sending data to another Activity
                nextScreen.putExtra("USERNAME", iwi1);
                //nextScreen.putExtra(spinner2.getContext().toString(), false);





                // starting new activity
                startActivity(nextScreen);




    }
        });

      }
      }
```

Comment: @StephenSugrue Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following code:

```
// find spinner object here
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
//get selected value here
String itemStr = spinnername1.getSelectedItem().toString();
//put selected vale and start new activity
Intent mIntent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, NewActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("data", itemStr);
startActivity(mIntent);


/**
* AT receiver side activity in onCreate
*/
Intent i = getIntent();
String dataString = i.getString("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the actual code you are using,

`String name1 = i.getStringExtra("");`

is wrong. What you put in `()` should be the key value that you used when you put the extra in your `Intent`. If you have

`myIntent.putExtra("myKey", myValue)`

then when you get the extra out of the `Intent` you need to use

`String name1 = i.getStringExtra("myKey");`

And this will give you the value of `myValue`. Use a different `key` for each `extra`.

If this doesn't do it then please post how you send the `Intent` data and where you seem to lose the values

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Spinner spinnername1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String mStr = spinnername1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

**For Pass Value into Intent**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("Value", mStr);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

**For Getting Value from Intent.**

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
String mValue = bdl.getString("Value");
```

Comment: Hi sorry about the delayed reply I have been busy over the weekend working another job. Here is my first class that gets the values from the spinners

Comment: I have modified my code (after a little more reading on Intents) I have no errors at run time but when I run in the emulator and press send button it crashes and says "...has stopped working" any ideas?

Comment: @StephenSugrue What error are you getting?, post error logcat in your question.